# How to apply weights – proportion of survey responses by different groups

Tags: r, math, dplyr, statistics, weighted-average

I've always had trouble with applying weights, so this is probably easy for you all.

I have survey data that has weights listed for each observation. I also have columns identifying demo1, demo2, and age group along with simple number responses for each question with corresponding columns. What I'm trying to do is find the proportion of my demo variables that picked certain answers based on a question. I can do that with the following code:

```
  data %>% 
  group_by(question1, demo1) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  group_by(demo1) %>%
  mutate(proportion =  count/sum(count))
```

However, I don't know how to accurately apply the corresponding weights, which are in a different column ("weights") and would help the results of the analysis reflect the demographics of the general population.

Thank you.

Comment: check the help for the `count` function. You'll notice that it has a `wt` parameter that might serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't show us your details so I'll be a little guessing what you expect.
See the example below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(weights)

n=100
df = tibble(
  question = rep(1:4, n),
  demo1 = rep(c("dem1", "dem2"), each=length(question)/2),
  demo2 = rep(c("dem1", "dem2", "dem3", "dem4"), each=length(question)/4),
  weight = sample(c(1,3,5,8), length(question), replace = TRUE)
)

fweight1 = function(data) tibble(
  prop = wpct(data$demo1, data$weight),
  demo1 = wpct(data$demo1, data$weight) %>% names())

df %>% group_by(question) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(prop1 = map(data, ~fweight1(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(prop1)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   question [4]
  question data                prop demo1
     <int> <list>             <dbl> <chr>
1        1 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.480 dem1 
2        1 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.520 dem2 
3        2 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.521 dem1 
4        2 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.479 dem2 
5        3 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.522 dem1 
6        3 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.478 dem2 
7        4 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.568 dem1 
8        4 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.432 dem2
```

And now the same for `demo2`

```
fweight2 = function(data) tibble(
  prop = wpct(data$demo2, data$weight),
  demo2 = wpct(data$demo2, data$weight) %>% names())

df %>% group_by(question) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(prop2 = map(data, ~fweight2(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(prop2)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   question [4]
   question data                prop demo2
      <int> <list>             <dbl> <chr>
 1        1 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.259 dem1 
 2        1 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.221 dem2 
 3        1 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.249 dem3 
 4        1 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.270 dem4 
 5        2 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.272 dem1 
 6        2 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.249 dem2 
 7        2 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.216 dem3 
 8        2 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.263 dem4 
 9        3 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.244 dem1 
10        3 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.278 dem2 
11        3 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.211 dem3 
12        3 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.267 dem4 
13        4 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.271 dem1 
14        4 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.297 dem2 
15        4 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.203 dem3 
16        4 <tibble [100 x 3]> 0.229 dem4
```

I used the `wpct` function from the `weights` package to calculate the proportions considering the weights.

Please confirm if this was your goal. Alternatively, share some of your data with us using the `dput` function.